# gdm3 display manager always starts with qwerty even though i only have dvorak installed

Tags: keyboard-layout, gdm

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 (with i3). I added the Dvorak keyboard layout and removed qwerty. If I go to keyboard -> settings, I only have Dvorak as an option in Input Sources. HOWEVER, whenever I restart and gdm3 launches the default language is QWERTY every time and I have to manually change the keyboard layout to dvorak. Is there a way to remove qwerty and only have Dvorak as default in gdm3 so that I don't have to manually make this selection each time?

Comment: What do you have in `/etc/default/keyboard`?

Comment: ```XKBLAYOUT="us,us"
XKBVARIANT="dvorak,"
XKBOPTIONS="caps:escape"
BACKSPACE="guess"
XKBMODEL="pc105"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me as if both qwerty and dvorak are available in `/etc/default/keyboard`. Maybe try to remove qwerty also there, i.e. replace

```
XKBLAYOUT="us,us"
XKBVARIANT="dvorak,"
```

with

```
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT="dvorak"
```

Comment: That did solve it, thanks.

Comment: If I did want to add qwerty back at some point, is there a way to make dvorak the default in gdm3?

Comment: @quiltedcomputer: Yes. First add it from Settings. Then make sure that `/etc/default/keyboard` still only contains dvorak.

Comment: great. confirming that worked.